# Django, how to iterate over one to many fields of different lengths

Tags: python, django

I pretty new to Django and I am trying to create an app to display tennis match results. So far, beyond my belief I have managed to hack together some code that is working.

However, I now have a problem though as currently I want to list the matches and their scores together in a template, but the number of sets can be different for each match and when I iterate through them I am getting an index error. Some matches may have 2 sets, others 3,4 or 5... perhaps some even just 1 if a player retires.

I have models for the match and each set, something like this. (I could get the match date, match, result and Set1 etc. for the player to display as those lists all have the same number of values. However, the length of list for set3 as an example is much shorter and causes an error.):

**models.py**

```
class Match(models.Model):
    match_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    match_date = models.DateField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through='MatchStats', related_name='pim')
    hometeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, to_field='teamname', related_name='hometeam')
    awayteam = models.ForeignKey(Team, to_field='teamname', related_name='awayteam')
    hometeam_sets = models.IntegerField()
    awayteam_sets = models.IntegerField()

class Set(models.Model):
    set_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    set_number = models.IntegerField()
    hometeam_games = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    awayteam_games = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
def playermatches(request, player_ID):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    p = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=player_ID)
    match_list = Match.objects.filter(players=player_ID).order_by('-match_date')[:100]

    i = len(match_list)
    j = 0

    #This works as all test matches have a 1st set!
    s1_list = Set.objects.filter(match=match_list, set_number=1).order_by(-match__match_date')[:100]
    """
    I am totally out of ideas as to what I might do next though. 
    Tried various things like 'if exists', 'try except IndexError etc'. 
    Below was the last thing I tried which failed yet again.
    """

    s3_list = []
    while j < i:
        s3 = Set.objects.filter(match=match_list, set_number=3)[j]
        if s3:
            s3_list.append(s2)
        else:
            s3 = Set.objects.filter(set_ID=1)
            s3_list.append(s3)

    lst1 = match_list
    lst2 = result_list
    lst3 = s1_list
    ...
    lst5 = s3_list

    mandr = zip(lst1, lst2, lst3,... lst5)

    context_dict = {...}
    return render_to_response('stats/players.html', context_dict, context)
```

**template.html**

```
{% if matches %}
    <ul>
        {% for match, team, s1, s2 in mandr %}
        <li>{{ match.match_date }} <a href="/stats/match/{{ match.match_ID }}/">{{ match.hometeam }} vs. {{ match.awayteam }}</a> ( {{ team.result }} )</li>
        <li>{{ match.hometeam_sets }}:{{ match.awayteam_sets }} -- {{ s1.hometeam_games }}-{{ s1.awayteam_games }} {{ s3.hometeam_games }}-{{ s3.awayteam_games }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <br/>
    <strong>There are currently no matches in the system - try again tomorrow!</strong>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't need anything too fancy in the end. Realized that I need to lookup the related sets via the foreign key for each match... and then simply iterate over those in the template.

```
{% for match in mandr %}
    {% for set in match.sets.all %}
        {{ set.hometeam_games }}:{{ set.awayteam_games }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix match list, result list with remaining lists. Pass them as separate objects in views and iterate over them in templates.

Change your views & template as follows.

**views.py**

```
m_list = match_list
r_list = result_list

list1 = s1_list
list2 = s2_list
..............
list5 = s3_list

mandr = zip(m_list, r_list)
my_lists = zip(list1, list2, ..., lst5)
```

**templates.py**

```
{% if matches %}
<ul>
    {% for match, team in mandr %}
    <li>{{ match.match_date }} <a href="/stats/match/{{ match.match_ID }}/">
    {{ match.hometeam }} vs. {{ match.awayteam }}</a> ( {{ team.result }} )</li>
    <li>{{ match.hometeam_sets }}:{{ match.awayteam_sets }} --
        {% for lst in my_lists %} 
            <li>{{ lst.hometeam_games }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <br/>
    <strong>There are currently no matches in the system - try again tomorrow!</strong>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Not quite what I wanted, but helped me see I was going off in completely the wrong direction with what I was trying to do.